# eliminate all indices of a file that don't conform to a certain format

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have a file of the form:

```
../input/test_input/7002/blah/blah/blah0.xml
../input/test_input/7002/blah/blah/blah1.xml
../input/test_input/7002/blah/blah/blah2.xml
../input/test_input/7002/blah/blah/blah3.xml
```

and so on, but every once in a while there will be a non-conformist, for instance a symlink that got picked up when I generated the file, i.e.:

```
../input/test_input/7002/blah/blah/blah4.xml
../input/test_input/
```

and I want to remove all of those imposters, i.e. `../input/test_input/` from the file since they're messing up my program.

How can I do that?

I just want to remove every index that doesn't conform to the format:

```
 ../input/test_input/7002/blah/blah/blahX.xml
```

since there are non-conformists of differing flavours, i.e. some look like this: `../input/test_input/`, and some like this: `../input/test_input/7002/` and so on.

So, I don't know exactly what I don't want. But I know what I do want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the lines which ends with `/`.

```
sed '/\/$/d' file
```

**OR**

Print only the lines which ends with `.xml`.

```
sed -n '/\.xml$/p' file
```

**OR**

Delete the lines which don't ends with `.xml`.

```
sed '/\.xml$/!d' file
```

Comment: so `sed` will just print them out and then I need to pipe them to a new file, is that it?

Comment: to save the output to new file use output redirection operator `sed -n '/\.xml$/p' file > newfile` , to do an inline-edit add `-i` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*\/$
```

Replace by empty string.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/17

Comment: so.. then i guess it's like: `perl ^.*\/$ file.txt`? is that right?

Comment: `perl m ^.*\/$ file.txt` like that? it takes a while to generate that file, so I don't want to make a mistake and screw it up.

Comment: @S.Matthew_English `perl -i -e 's/^.*\/$//gsm' something like this

Answer (score 0):

Delete (`d`) lines not matching the pattern in-place (`-i`):

```
sed -i '\#\.\./input/test_input/7002/blah/blah/blah[0-9]*\.xml#d' input
```